# How to pull data from Google Form and display result before submission?

Tags: google-forms

Say I have a google form here: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1HnATawk6ioE7_EVKrtszxvScjmUSF7_ma0_9XhBZ-hw/viewform

The user will input numbers.

As a confirmation before they submit the form, I'd like to use those numbers to display the analysis of the data which they can verify before submission. (To be precise, I'd like to display the sum of the first 4 numbers, then the sum of the next 4 numbers, then state which sum is bigger, and by how much)

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is to create dynamic data in Google Forms without clicking the submit button.

**This is NOT possible in Google Forms**. Please have a look at the [available triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#available_types_of_triggers).

Since there can be no triggers activated after the form is loaded, there can be no interaction while filling and before submitting the form. Not even using a script.

Having said that your other choice would be to use the HtmlService or the UiServise instead and build your own web app.