# How to redirect google form

Tags: google-forms

Hi am new to google spreadsheet and forms.

I have a form with 3 radio buttons. I want to redirect to 3 different URL's based on the option selected. Is there any way that I can redirect to 3 different urls based on option selected??

Comment: Another browser tab or browser window can not be opened from the user choosing anything on the Google Form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sandy is right.

You cannot interact with the form before submission.
Please have a look at: [How to pull data from Google Form and display result before submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36091041/how-to-pull-data-from-google-form-and-display-result-before-submission)
The closest you could get based on answers,

[image: what to look for]

would be to have users go to sections with no questions and advise them to click on the link.

[image: advise redirecting]

On the other hand I cannot understand why you would want to redirect users to "*different urls based on option selected*". If they get redirected upon selecting an option, they will never reach the submit button, which renders the use of a form pointless.